# Custom js file not loading in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to run some javascript libraries in wordpress for a finance calculator. I can run this calculator no problem stand alone, just as a html file. see link here http://78.129.155.241/~ryedalel/calculate/

This works fine but as soon as I try to make a page in wordpress to display this calculator it does not work. See this link http://78.129.155.241/~ryedalel/calculate-wordpress/

I have disabled all plugins and changed to default theme but the error still remains. I have also followed various tutorials to correctly enqueue the script as required by wordpress but still the error is there.

This is the first time I have tried to add custom javascript to wordpress so I'm probably missing something fundamental here but I have no idea what.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

The calculator code is below:

```
<div ng-controller="financeCalcController"><![if gte IE 9]><div ng-controller="financeCalcController"><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://78.129.155.241/~ryedalel/calculate/js/jquery.nouislider.css" /><link href='http://78.129.155.241/~ryedalel/calculate/js/app.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'><div class="finance-calc"><div id="finance-popup-inner"><h2>Finance options with Black Horse</h2><section class="finance-form"><p>How much are you looking to finance, and for how long?</p><div class="cost finance-slider"><div class="cost">£<input style='width: 80%' ng-model="cost"/><span class='finance-caption'>Cost</span></div><div ng-click="calcchange = true" class="slideui" slider ng-model="cost" start=2500 end=40000 step=100></div></div><div class="cost finance-slider"><div class="cost">£<input style='width: 80%' ng-model="deposit"/><span class='finance-caption'>Deposit</span></div><div ng-click="calcchange = true" class="slideui" slider ng-model="deposit" start=0 end=40000 step=10></div></div><div class="months finance-slider"><div class="cost"><h4 class="value" ng-bind="( months ) + ' months'"></h4><span class='finance-caption'>Duration</span></div><div ng-click="calcchange = true" class="slideui" slider ng-model="months" start=12 end=84 step=12></div></div><button ng-click="calculatePayments()" ng-bind="( calcchange && nocalc == false| switch : 'Recalculate finance' : 'Calculate finance'  )"></button></section><section id="finance-results" ng-class="{changed: calcchange}"><img src="images/blackhorse-finance-calculator.jpg" style="width: 60%;"><h3>Repayment plan</h3><p>We can offer you the following repayment plan:</p><dl><div class="finance-prop"><dt ng-bind="( months ) + ' monthly payments'"></dt><dd ng-bind="( payment.term | currency: '£' )"></dd></div><div class="finance-prop total"><dt>Total</dt><dd ng-bind="( payment.total | currency: '£'  )"></dd></div><p>At <span ng-bind='(apr * 100)'></span>% APR Representative, you'd pay that off by <span ng-bind="( payment.enddate | date : 'MMM yyyy' )"></span><br><small><small>* Finance is subject to status and is only available to UK residents aged 18 and over. Finance provided by Black Horse Limited, St William House, Tresillian Terrace, Cardiff CF10 5BH.</small></small></p><p><small>Ryedale Caravans is authorised by the FCA with Limited Permission to conduct certain credit related activity</small><br /><small>We are a credit broker/intermediary and can introduce you to a limited number of lenders who provide funding.  We may receive commission or other benefits for introducing you to such lenders.</small></p></dl><div class="clearfix"></div></section></div></div></div><script src='http://78.129.155.241/~ryedalel/calculate/js/libs.min.js'></script><script src='http://78.129.155.241/~ryedalel/calculate/js/app.min.js'>/script><![endif]></div>'
```

Comment: Does you calculator rely on jquery? I know wordpress is a pain in the ass with jquery, you have to run it in no conflict mode and adapt your code a bit to get it to work

Comment: Read about enqueue_script function, that will help you... your JS files was not included properly.. it seems...

Comment: Yes Alice I did try to use wp_enqueue_script but it didn't work for me. Maybe I missed something, I will give it another try. The two scripts I am trying to run are: libs.min.js and app.min.js

Comment: I'm running wp 4.7.4 Mokkun, I believe it runs in no conflict mode by default?

Comment: Thanks for the snippets CyberAbhay but unfortunately I have tried both methods and it does not solve the problem. With your first method nothing changed and no errors were thrown. On the second method it throws the following error: Warning: filemtime(): stat failed for /home/ryedalel/public_html/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-The‌​me/calculate-finance‌​/js/libs.min.js in /home/ryedalel/public_html/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-The‌​me/functions.php on line 17 I am a complete novice with js and I would be happy to pay to get this resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In jquery adding external css in different for font-end and back-end
This is small function which can solve your problem

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'add_custom_scripts_and_styles_report' );
function add_custom_scripts_and_styles_report() {
   wp_enqueue_script( 'uniquename_custom_js', plugins_url( 'js/custom.js?'.rand(), __FILE__ ), array('jquery'), '1.0', true );

}
```

here rand() will and version to you js to solve caching problem and j query is for if your js is depend on j query.

OR

```
function my_load_scripts($hook) {

    // create my own version codes
    $my_js_ver  = date("ymd-Gis", filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'js/custom.js' ));
    $my_css_ver = date("ymd-Gis", filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'style.css' ));

    // 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_js', plugins_url( 'js/custom.js', __FILE__ ), array(), $my_js_ver );
    wp_register_style( 'my_css',    plugins_url( 'style.css',    __FILE__ ), false,   $my_css_ver );
    wp_enqueue_style ( 'my_css' );

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_load_scripts');
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippets CyberAbhay but unfortunately I have tried both methods and it does not solve the problem. With your first method nothing changed and no errors were thrown. On the second method it throws the following error: Warning: filemtime(): stat failed for /home/ryedalel/public_html/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/calculate-finance/js/libs.min.js in /home/ryedalel/public_html/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/functions.php on line 17
I am a complete novice with js and I would be happy to pay to get this resolved.